# Confirm Email Sent by Displaying Sent/Not Sent Text

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

My goal is to know when an email has been sent.

I have msgbox code to know all email addresses have been processed.

My coding looks at cells/columns that are filled. I have a column where I list email addresses, a column for the body of the email, a column for the path to attachments, etc.

I want to add a "Status" for every email address. I want to say Sent or Not Sent (not sent would be if it was an invalid email address).

Now if an email address is invalid it debugs. I don't want to wait till it debugs to figure out it is not a valid email address.  I want each row with an email address to say sent or not sent but keep sending even if it is not a valid email address.

The msgbox is great if it doesn't debug. I want to keep the msgbox.

Layout in my Excel workbook. I would like the sent and not sent to populate in the Status column.
[image: Email Template]

```vb
Sub Send_Multiple_Emails()
dim sh as worksheet
set sh = thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1") '<-- rename to what the tabs name is

dim OA as Object
Dim msg As object

set OA = createobject("Outlook.Application")

Dim i as integer
dim last_row As Integer

last_row = application.worksheetfunction.counta(sh.range("B:B"))

for i = 2 To last_row

    Set msg = OA.createitem(0)

    msg.to = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
    msg.cc = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
    msg.subject = sh.range("D" & i ).Value
    msg.body = sh.Range("E" & i).Value

    if sh.Range("F" & i).Value <> "" Then
        msg.attachments.add sh.range("F" & i).Value
        msg.send


next i

msgbox "Mails Sent"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rare situation `On Error Resume Next` can be appropriate.

Bypass the expected error to handle it in the code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RecognizeSendError()

    Dim OA As Object
    Dim msg As Object
    
    Dim msgSent As Boolean
        
    Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set msg = OA.CreateItem(0)
    
    msg.To = "NotValid"
    Debug.Print "msg.To: " & msg.To
    
    msg.Subject = "subject"
    msg.Body = "body"
    
    ' use only for a specific purpose
    On Error Resume Next
    
    msg.Send
        
    ' deal with expected error
    If Err <> 0 Then
        'Debug.Print " Err: " & Err
        msgSent = False
    Else
        msgSent = True
    End If
    
    ' Return to normal error handling for unexpected errors
    ' Consider mandatory after On Error Resume Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If msgSent Then
        Debug.Print " Success"
    Else
        Debug.Print " Failure"
    End If
        
    Debug.Print "Done"

End Sub
```